# Is a val in a scala method (def) on a case class (or an object for that matter) calculated only once?

Tags: scala

As per this example will the calculation for someValue be ran only once for each instance of the class?

```
case class MyThing {

  def myMethod {
    val someValue = 19 * 27
    someValue
  }

}
```

Would the same rules apply to an `object`

```
object MyObject {

  def myMethod {
    val someValue = 19 * 27
    someValue
  }

}
```

If you have an immutable case class (and of course objects are immutable by virtue of being a single instance) then there is no sense in re-running calculations that have been ran, even if they use values in the class itself (I'm thinking of custom hashCode calculations for example).

Is the compiler smart enough to handle that or would it be better to place the val outside of the def? (Making it lazy so it only gets called when needed...)

Comment: Just a reminder for future visitors: on Objects, `val` seems to act as as `lazy val`; run the following code to check it: `object O{val v1 = {println("ran once"); 1}};`; then call `O.v1;` twice. You will see that message bring printed only once.

Answer (score 2):

The literal is inlined at compile time:

```
scala> object O { def f = 19*27 }
defined object O

scala> :javap -c O
Compiled from "<console>"
public class O$ {

  public int f();
    Code:
       0: sipush        513
       3: ireturn

  <snip>
}
```

Generally, the Scala compiler doesn't optimize such cases when there are no literals involved:

```
scala> object O { def f = g*h; def g = 19; def h = 27 }
defined object O

scala> :javap -c O
Compiled from "<console>"
public class O$ {

  public int f();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokevirtual #17                 // Method g:()I
       4: aload_0
       5: invokevirtual #20                 // Method h:()I
       8: imul
       9: ireturn

  public int g();
    Code:
       0: bipush        19
       2: ireturn

  public int h();
    Code:
       0: bipush        27
       2: ireturn

  <snip>
}
```

When you write `def`, then you mean `def`, i.e. every time you call the method everything in it is evaluated. Anything that should be cached needs to be done manually on your side.

In the above example however, it is very likely that the JVM itself will inline `g` and `h`, with the result that the first and the second example will be optimized to the same machine code.

Comment: Same result for the product of two class parameters. It is not memoized, even under -optimize. But it's not a naive question, so, sorry somebody downvoted. You could imagine an option to request it. -Yopt:time.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put: No.

`val` is only evaluated once.

`def` is evaluated every time.

That is the difference between those keywords in the Scala language.

As `myMethod` has no parameters and is not affected by side-effects, it should be changed to `val` or as you say `lazy val` so it is only ran when needed.

It is more productive to program with intent rather than rely on compiler optimisation.

Comment: Yes but my question was what happens in the specific case of a val inside a def? This was a completely trivial example so that a very precise question could be answered. And yes I understand completely val versus def but I do not yet fully understand the interactions of those two as they can be nested (as per my example).